# ARC Semantic Issue Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am creating an ios application in objective-c with xcode and came across a strange error.
the code is:

```
#import "LAAppDelegate.h"
#import "Reachability.h"

@implementation LAAppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    NetworkStatus networkStatus =
        [[Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]
         currentReachabilityStatus];
    if (networkStatus == NotReachable) {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
        initWithTite:@"Network Unavailable"
        message:@"Lazuli requires an internet connection"
        delegate:nil
        cancelButtonTitle:@"Ignore"
        otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];

    }

   // Override point for customization after application launch.
   return YES;
}
```

I keep getting the error:  "No visible @interface for 'UIAlertView' declares the selector 'initWithTite:message:delegate:cancelButtonTitle:otherButtonTitles:' "

I am a beginner and need help!

Comment: you has to change initWithTite for initWithTitle, you miss the 'l'

Comment: As an aside, calling Reachability that way is wrong in two ways. You should attempt a connection using NSURLConnection since the radio on the device might be powered down and NSURLConnection will power it up. Reachability will not. Also, if the network is up but not working well, your app will lock up and be terminated. Never make a synchronous network call on the main thread and that includes Reachability.

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo in your method call. It's initWith**Title**..., not initWith**Tite**...

Comment: Wow, I answered this almost 5 months ago, but you're welcome :-)

Comment: :) Sorry, I just checked now. I don't use my account much.

Comment: Do you have any input on this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/16020996/1941140    I would much appreciate any help! :)